# running shell_exec gives error that I don't get when typing on command line

Tags: java, php

I don't know if this is a Java problem, PHP problem, or server problem or ?:

On server, I can ssh and run command `java -version` and outputs version okay.

Run `shell_exec('java -version')` or `exec('java -version')` in PHP script and I get this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for object heap

running `shell_exec('whoami')` / `exec('whoami')` shows I am the user when running shell_exec/exec

Also tried running same full path in both cases - `/usr/bin/java -version`

Any ideas?

Server is running Debian squeeze

EDIT:

also tried wrapping java command in a shell script - no go...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -XX option, for example:

```
java -Xms32m MyProgram
```

If it did not work try with higher values and see what you get.

Hope this helps